# Create Prepared SQL Statement where in the SQL Statement already equal values (SQL Injection)

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

created a form that gets posts by user id. my question is:
**how do you convert this to a prepared statement.** seen where you assign a var for a value, however **how would you prepare a SQL statement that already equals a value in the request?** Statement is:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts, users WHERE posts.user_id = users.id AND
 posts.user_id = ".$_GET['uid'];"
```

**Complete PHP Statement**
            *this code also runs "**PHP functions**" but should not be needed for writeup (I suspect)

                                    If it does please let me know and I can supply them.*

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['uid'])) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM posts, users WHERE posts.user_id = users.id
                    AND posts.user_id = ".$_GET['uid'];
} else {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM posts, users WHERE posts.user_id = users.id
                    ORDER BY post_id DESC";
}

include_once('dbconnect.php');
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result) {
    error_reporting(1);
    echo mysql_error();
}

$postID=$_GET['pid'];
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['post_id'].$row['post_title'].$row['username'];
    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        if(getSessionUserId() == $row['user_id']) {
            echo $row['post_id'].$row['post_id'];
        }
    }
    echo substr($row['post_content'], 0, 200).$row['post_id'];
}
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't get easier than this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: yeah misread that; this database is dynamic (obviously it is SQL) and creates and retrieves posts from database much like WordPress. the value can not equal static value like '1' or '2' it must equal a range or all but sort at the same time.

Comment: <?php
 /* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
 if(!($stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts, users WHERE posts.user_id = users.id AND posts.user_id = ".$_GET['uid'])))
 {
  echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
  $stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts, users WHERE posts.user_id = users.id ORDER BY post_id DESC");
 }
 ...
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) found out that I needed to create an array that set names to UTF8; once that was done I was able to connect to Server.
 (2) then needed to send call to server.
 
 (3) then fetch results from server [fetchAll()]

```
<?php
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DATABASE';
    $username = 'USERNAME';
    $password = 'PASSWORD';
    $options = array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8', PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
    );

    try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        echo '<h4 class="text-success">PDO connection created Successfully</h4>';
        print '<h4 class="text-info">Connection Info: </h4><p class="text-warning">'.$dsn.'</p>';
        print '<p class="text-warning"><b>Username: </b>'.$username.'</p><br />';
    }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo '<p class="text-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        die();
    }

    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts, users WHERE posts.user_id = users.id ORDER BY post_id DESC');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo '<h3><a href="viewpost.php?pid='.$row['post_id'].'">'.$row['post_title'].'</a></h3>';  #Post Title
        echo '<p class="text-success col-md-12" name="marketing-section" id="marketing-section"> Author: <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form-content">'.$row['username'].'</a></p>';
        echo '<p class="lead col-md-12">'.substr($row['post_content'], 0, 200).'<a href="viewpost.php?pid='.$row['post_id'].'"> ...More</a></p><br /><hr>';
    }
?>
```

Works Great now! See it at **[Create Prepared SQL Statement: Demo](http://soldierupdesigns.com/test.php).**